# Textbox tapped event don't fire on windows 8 for mouse click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps, mouseclick-event

I have the following code that builds me a text box.
The application requires me to make all my controls generic,
as that is the way our api is sending it to us.

```
TextBox txtcontent = new TextBox();
txtcontent.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
txtcontent.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
txtcontent.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, RowCount);
txtcontent.Width = 320;
txtcontent.FontSize = 20;
txtcontent.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
txtcontent.Margin = new Thickness(10);
txtcontent.Foreground = App.scbAccTechGrayDark;
txtcontent.BorderBrush = App.scbAccTechGrayLight;
txtcontent.Background = App.scbAccTechGreenLight;
txtcontent.Tapped += txtcontent_Tapped;
```

Now the problem is when I click on the textbox it does not fire the tapped event.
I understand that the mouse click will fire the tapped event for a store app?

Here is 1st part of the tapped event, but I never reach it.

```
void txtcontent_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtFinder = (sender as TextBox);
    string[] myconver = (sender as TextBox).Tag.ToString().Split(',');
    int BlockIndex = Convert.ToInt16(myconver[4].ToString());
    int FieldID = Convert.ToInt16(myconver[5].ToString());
    string ColumnName = Convert.ToString(myconver[6].ToString());
    string FieldCode = Convert.ToString(myconver[7]);
    string BlockName = Convert.ToString(myconver[8]);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what i must do, or what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: what behaivor do you want to implement? Maybe the GotFocus event is working for you.

Comment: @Anubis1233 thanks mate that works as i needed, if you make it an answer i will choose it for you. actually very obvious now that i think baout it! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.gotfocus%20%27GotFocus%27)  event of the [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox%20%27TextBox%27) control.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to associated Tapped Event to the Textbox using AddHandler method.

```
txtcontent.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(txtcontent_Tapped), true);

  void txtcontent_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tested!!");
        }
```

Here is completed code snippet for the same.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            AddControl();
        }



        private void AddControl()
        {
            TextBox txtcontent = new TextBox();
            txtcontent.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            txtcontent.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
            txtcontent.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
            txtcontent.Width = 150;
            txtcontent.FontSize = 20;
            txtcontent.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            txtcontent.Margin = new Thickness(10);
            txtcontent.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(txtcontent_Tapped), true);
            //txtcontent.Foreground = new Solid
            //txtcontent.BorderBrush = App.scbAccTechGrayLight;
            //txtcontent.Background = App.scbAccTechGreenLight;
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(txtcontent);
        }


        void txtcontent_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tested by WmDev!!");
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void txtbox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtbox.Text = ""; // da e34n el txtbox yb2a empty when clicked ;)
    }
```

try this ;)